# e1000e device loses dhcp lease repatedly

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, dhcp

I have a M70q mini PC that is using the e1000e device driver for the ethernet connection. Whenever I attempt to ftp a file to the computer, it loses its IP address. It will regain the IP address but it will only hold on to it for a couple minutes and then it will drop again over and over. From what I've seen online, the "lost carrier" is typically something with the physical connection although I've replaced the ethernet cable multiple times and switched router ports as well.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Netplan config:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno2:
      addresses:
          - 192.168.12.185/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.12.1
      mtu: 9000
```

Ifconfig interface stats:

```
eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
    inet 192.168.12.185  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.12.255
    inet6 fe80::6e24:8ff:fe14:73ab  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2607:fb91:3f2e:1161:6e24:8ff:fe14:73ab  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 2607:fb91:3f2e:1161:107d:5739:0:22e  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether 6c:24:08:14:73:ab  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 3866534  bytes 4333695123 (4.3 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 7  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4863702  bytes 3497649374 (3.4 GB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16  memory 0xb1200000-b1220000
```

Syslog output:

```
systemd-networkd[891]: eno2: Lost carrier
kernel: [352082.226632] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno2: NIC Link is Down
systemd-networkd[891]: eno2: DHCPv6 lease lost
systemd-timesyncd[852]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
kernel: [352084.981150] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno2: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
systemd-networkd[891]: eno2: Gained carrier
systemd-timesyncd[852]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
systemd-timesyncd[852]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
systemd-timesyncd[852]: Initial synchronization to time server 185.125.190.57:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
systemd-networkd[891]: eno2: DHCPv6 address 2607:fb91:3f2e:1161:107d:5739:0:22e/128 (valid for 1d, preferred for 1d)
```

Comment: Does it only happen during `ftp`?  What about `curl`, `wget` or a web browser?

Comment: @RonJohn - I believe it does happen via wget although I don't think those exchanges typically last long enough to conclusively tell. Is there some place I can wget a large test file?

Comment: @guiverc - Sorry! I totally forgot to mention. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Ubuntu ISO files are pretty big... :D

Comment: @RonJohn - Oh of course!!

Comment: @RonJohn Yes it does occur with wget as well. Tried to download the ISO and it almost immediately lost the lease.

Comment: Maybe your router is wonky?

Comment: You have listed that you are using a static IP yet your title says that you are losing DHCP.  You could be experiencing an IP conflict.  See:  https://netplan.io/examples  If you want to use DHCP you need to have it as `dhcp4: yes`

Comment: You might be experiencing a reset of the NIC.  See:  https://gist.github.com/amit177/63c86ee05110091f6fdda4c87a4209d0